# How to export the configuration of a project in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-developers-console

I want to download (export) the configuration of a Google Cloud project, to keep safe because I need to delete some projects.
Thank you.
Guillermo

I try to look in the documentation but I find nothing. :-(